Unable to connect to any API via CCXT in VSC - keep returning an unauthorized/401 client error. What is wrong?
Here is what the terminal tells me with every failed connection (I've tried Kraken Futures, Phemex Testnet, Coinbase Demo account):
(cryptobot) PS C:\Users\jcazi\OneDrive\Desktop\Algotrading> & C:/Users/jcazi/Anaconda3/envs/cryptobot/python.exe c:/Users/jcazi/OneDrive/Desktop/Algotrading/algo_orders.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jcazi\Anaconda3\envs\cryptobot\lib\site-packages\ccxt\base\exchange.py", line 645, in fetch
    response.raise_for_status()
  File "C:\Users\jcazi\Anaconda3\envs\cryptobot\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 1021, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 401 Client Error: Unauthorized for url: https://api.phemex.com/spot/wallets

Here is my code I am running (I double checked API key and secret are correct/are strings and they are imported from another doc in the same folder):
import ccxt
from keyfile import key
from keyfile import secret


phemex = ccxt.phemex ({
    'enableRateLimit': True,
    'apiKey': key,
    'secret': secret
    })

phemex.fetch_balance()

I tried multiple exchanges, generating multiple new multiple API keys, updating ccxt, entering the key/secret manually in the code as strings without import, consulting chatgpt, and more.

maybe you use wrong API Keys. Different portals may use different API Keys. Portals may need also to select privileges on portal.

during generating API key I see Effective within 30 minutes after creation. - so maybe you have to wait 30 minutes. And in Google I found places which runs code with parameters exchange.fetch_balance(params={"type": "swap", "code": "USDT"}) and maybe you also need it.

phemex fetch_balance not showing contract USD account balances? · Issue #8325 · ccxt/ccxt

code works for phemex.fetch_markets() and phemex.fetch_currencies() but not for phemex.fetch_balance() - maybe it needs Account Verification
